# Windows update priority rollout

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I'm currently having windows 10 build 1803, and I'm interested in some features of windows 10 1809. However, Windows update indicates that my software is up to date. Microsoft provides with an updater to manually update to version 1809, however, on my computer, it fails during installation, and reverts changes.

Another solution to get these features would be to sign up for the Windows Insider Program, but that means that I would have more unstable versions of Windows.

Is there a way to indicate to windows update that you wish to get the newest upgrade, or in any way to accelerate the process of making this update available on my computer?

EDIT: 
I've had several boot problems due to a clone of my system to a newest disk that I've added to my computer. The boot process seems to have been very disturbed by the presence of two identicals boot routines and GPT tables. I've repaired my windows bootmanager and wiped my oldest disk. I've been able to get the update 1809 through the semi annual channel as suggested. It is currently downloading through windows update and I will try the installation afterwards

Comment: Which channel are you currently configured to.  Semi-Annual Targeted or Semi-Annual?  If you want help with issue we have to solve the reason the upgrade failed.  The upgrade process using the upgrade assistance and Windows Update is identical.

Comment: But, if you've already _received_ the update via the helper app, and it only fails during _installation_ (rather than search or download), why do you expect regular Windows Update to provide something different? It's going to be the same build.

Comment: The process looks rather different visually speaking. If you're saying the installation process itself is the same then I believe it will indeed fail if I use the classical update process or if it is updated automatically. Then my problem will indeed be to understand why it fails. @Ramhound I do not know which channel I'm on. How does one determine it?

Comment: @PoutchiPatch - It isn't that visually different.  You download the release in the background, the majority of the installation process is performed in the background, and only when you get to the stage that requires a reboot will you be logged out of Windows.  That process will happen regardless of the method you use to install the feature update.  Settings -> Windows Update is where you configured the channel, if this is not a personal machine, I would not change it

Comment: @PoutchiPatch - I have voted to reopen this question, however, we need to know the reason the upgrade failed.  Otherwise, the question as it's currently written is too broad, I don't believe it's a duplicate question though.

Comment: Your question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Instead of asking how to *"indicate to windows update that you wish to get the newest upgrade,"* please ask how to fix the upgrade installer crashing.

Comment: I'll update the post with the latest news